# Dplyr::Filter Three or More Conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've a data frame which I want to narrow down from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

```
a<- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
b<- c(2, 1, 3, 3, NA) 
c <- c(3, 1, 1, 3, 2)
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)

# Will Loose Data in Real Life Example
df %>%
    filter(a == 1, b >= 3) %>%
    filter(., c ==3)

## Doesn't Work
filter(df , all(a == 1, b >= 3, c == 3))
filter(df, (a==1 && b>=3 && c ==3))
```

Is there a *tidyverse*-esque way of doing this without using multiple 'and' operations?

Comment: `filter(df, a==1, b>=2, c==3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `&&` use `&`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter((a==1 & b>=2 & c ==3))
#  a b c
#1 1 2 3
#2 1 3 3
```